# 500 (Internal Server Error) [Laravel 5.2]

Tags: javascript, laravel

i got an error about internal server error when retrieving data from database

here is the route

```
Route::get('retrieve',function() {
    $tourism = \App\Models\Tourism::orderBy('rating','desc')->take(6)->get();

    return $tourism;
});
```

but when i did

```
$tourism = \App\Models\Tourism::all()
```

the data is exist.

this is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var lokasi = [];
        var URL = '{{URL::to('/retrieve')}}';
        var htmlURL = '{{URL::to('/tourismplace/id/')}}';
        $.get(URL).success(function(data){
            var jumlahData = data.length;
            for(var i=0;i<jumlahData;i++){
                lokasi.push({
                    lat : data[i].latitude,
                    lon : data[i].longitude,
                    zoom : 18,
                    title : data[i].nama,
                    html : "<a href='"+htmlURL+"/"+data[i].id +"'>"+data[i].nama+"</a>",
                    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png', // custom icon
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP

                });
            }
            new Maplace({
                locations: lokasi,
                map_div: '#gmap-menu',
                controls_type: 'list',
                show_markers: true,
                visualRefresh:true,
                controls_on_map:false
            }).Load();
            console.log(lokasi);
        });
    });
```

last 4 logs

```
#53 C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsiproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
    #54 C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsiproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #55 C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsiproject\public\index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #56 {main}
```

the first 4 logs

```
   #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsiproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(333): PDO->prepare('select * from `...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsiproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(706): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection), 'select * from `...', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsiproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(669): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsiproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(342): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
```

Comment: Any error message from logs?

Comment: @huuk yes, it says in the console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: it's error message from your browser, can you show error message from you web server?

Comment: And in the log? /storage/logs/laravel.log?

Comment: @huuuk how can i do that? i'm still a beginner

Comment: @RobinDirksen this is the last 4 logs in the log #53 C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsiproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#54 C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsiproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#55 C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsiproject\public\index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#56 {main}

Comment: can you add it to your question? @user2871904

Comment: @RobinDirksen already put it

Comment: Add the first 4 starting at **#0** and include the error message which should start with the date like this **[2016-05-27...**.

Comment: @TheFallen yes i just put it

Comment: Please include the line above **#0** that tells the exact error and starts with something like this **[2016-05-27....**.

Comment: yeah u r right, i just realized it, i used column that exist in another table. thank you very much sir @TheFallen

Comment: Great, glad I could help :)